# node-webkit screensaver (.scr)

Tags: node-webkit

I have been successfully able to make a node-webkit app and create and exe to distribute, I am doing so using

```
copy /b nw.exe+app.nw app.exe
```

so I then have a folder with the app.exe and various other file (.dll, .pax and .bat).

My question is two fold:

1: can I package all of the files into the .exe (so I only have one file)

2: can I have this as a .scr (screensaver)

Any help or pointer would be really appreciated.

Comment: A screensaver is an executable with another suffix, renaming is sufficient

Comment: The screensaver will be pushed out to a number of machines through an Intranet/network. Will this still work with the external files (.dll,  .pak...etc...)? any screensavers I have seen are standalone files.

Comment: Did you get this working as a screen saver? Did it work to deploy it to multiple machines?

Comment: No I never came to a conclusion on this.  My compaby have a 5mb size limit,  which meant that I would have been waiting my time. I am still interested in finding a solution though.